# How to upload media to twitter in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twitter

I am creating TwitterClient in Unity to tweet using Unity Assets.

but this library doesn't have media upload method.

so I wrote upload method modeling tweet method.

but it returns `400 Bad Request: Code 214 BadRequest` from TwitterAPI.

```
public static IEnumerator UploadPic(string picture, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, AccessTokenResponse response, UploadPicCallback callback)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // parameters.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");

    // Add data to the form to post.
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField("media_data", picture);
    form.AddField("additional_owners", "");
    //form.AddField("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
    //form.AddField(picture, "");

    // HTTP header
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    headers["Authorization"] = GetHeaderWithAccessToken("POST", UploadPicURL, consumerKey, consumerSecret, response, parameters);
    headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in headers)
    {
        Debug.Log(x.Key + ":" + x.Value);
    }

    /*
    string auth = GetHeaderWithAccessToken("POST", UploadPicURL, consumerKey, consumerSecret, response, parameters);
    headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
    headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    */

    WWW web = new WWW(UploadPicURL, form.data, headers);

    yield return web;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(web.error))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("UploadPic - failed. {0}\n{1}", web.error, web.text));
        callback(false, web.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string error = Regex.Match(web.text, @"<error>([^&]+)</error>").Groups[1].Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("UploadPic - failed. {0}", error));
            callback(false, web.error);
        }
        else
        {
            callback(true, web.text);
        }
    }

}
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks for your help.